# Sliding text on button caption like marquee with css and javascript (Not jQuery)

Tags: javascript, css, animation, sencha-touch

I have multiple buttons with dynamic text. I want right to left circular sliding effect on the each buttons text with javascript or CSS. Not use jQuery. See below scenario

[image]

**Update**

**My current Code**

```css
/* Make it a marquee */
    .marquee {
        width: 200px;margin: 0 auto;white-space: nowrap;overflow: hidden;
    }
    .marquee span {
        display: inline-block;
        padding-left: 100%;
        text-indent: 0;
        animation: marquee 10s linear infinite;
    }
    .marquee span:hover {
        animation-play-state: paused
    }/* Make it move */
    @keyframes marquee {
        0% { transform: translate(0, 0); }
        30% { transform: translate(-43%, 0); }
        60% { transform: translate(-43%, 0); }
        100% { transform: translate(-100%, 0); }
    }
```

```html
<button class="marquee">
  <span>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text</span>
</button>
<button class="marquee">
  <span>LoremLorem Ipsum is simply dummy Ipsum is simply dummy text</span>
</button>
```

But it's not working properly on dynamic text on the button.

Comment: What did you try? share your code, then we can help

Comment: I have added code to the question. Please check it and help me.

Answer (score 2):

I have removed your padding, so that now the span is aligned with the button.

Since the buttons are always 200px wide, now the first keyframe should be 200px to the right. And the others keyframes are just equally easy:

```css
/* Make it a marquee */
    .marquee {
        width: 200px;margin: 0 auto;white-space: nowrap;overflow: hidden;
    }
    .marquee span {
        display: inline-block;
        text-indent: 0;
        animation: marquee 10s linear infinite;
    }
    .marquee span:hover {
        animation-play-state: paused
    }/* Make it move */
    @keyframes marquee {
        0% { transform: translate(200px, 0); }
        30% { transform: translate(0, 0); }
        60% { transform: translate(0, 0); }
        100% { transform: translate(-100%, 0); }
    }
```

```html
<button class="marquee">
  <span>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text</span>
</button>
<button class="marquee">
  <span>LoremLorem Ipsum is simply dummy Ipsum is simply dummy text</span>
</button>
```